# Shorten JSX Attribute Syntax

Tags: syntax, jsx

My code includes a lot of "myClass" (JSX).
How can I shorten the syntax?
I tried to reference to it as a func and const.
So here is my code:

```
<form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
<article className={styles[0]}>
<main className={styles[1]}>
    <fieldset id="sign_in" className={styles[3]}>
        <legend className={styles[3]}>SIGN IN</legend>
        <div className="mt3">
            <label className="db fw6 lh-copy f6" id="email-address">EMAIL</label>
            <input className={styles[2]}
                type="email" name="email" value={this.state.email} 
                onChange={this.handleChange} />                       
        </div>
        <div className="mv3">
            <label className="db fw6 lh-copy f6">PASSWORD</label>
            <input className={styles[2]} 
                type="password" name="password" value={this.state.password}  
                onChange={this.handleChange} />
        </div>
        <label className="pa0 ma0 lh-copy f6 pointer">REMEMBER ME&nbsp;<input type="checkbox"/></label>
    </fieldset>
    <div className="">
        <input className="b ph3 pv2 input-reset ba b--black bg-transparent grow pointer f6 dib" 
            type="submit" value="SUBMIT" />
    </div>
    <br></br>
    <div className="lh-copy mt3">
        <a href="#0" className="f5 link dim black db">SIGN UP</a>
        <a href="#0" className="f5 link dim black db">FORGOT THE PASSWORD</a>
    </div> 
</main>
</article>
</form>
```

Comment: Please provide the code you're referring to.

Comment: I provided the code